# coding-system for append-to-file

Tags: emacs24.4

I am using

```
(setq a-string "\n* Headline \n body")
(append-to-file a-string nil "~/tmp.org")
```

to write a string to a org file, since the string contains a `*`, Emacs ask me to choose which coding system,

`Select coding system (default raw-text):`

I wonder if there is any way I can remove this prompt and set it to `utf-8` automatically?

**Example**: I get the following message on Emacs

These default coding systems were tried to encode "
* apple 
...":

(prefer-utf-8-unix (215 . 4194274) (216 . 4194176) (217 . 4194196)
  (460 . 4194274) (461 . 4194176) (462 . 4194196)) (utf-8-unix (215
  . 4194274) (216 . 4194176) (217 . 4194196) (460 . 4194274) (461
  . 4194176) (462 . 4194196))

However, each of them encountered characters it couldn't encode:

prefer-utf-8-unix cannot encode these: \342 \200 \224 \342 \200 \224

utf-8-unix cannot encode these: \342 \200 \224 \342 \200 \224

Click on a character (or switch to this window by `C-x o'
and select the characters by RET) to jump to the place it appears,
where`C-u C-x =' will give information about it.

Select one of the safe coding systems listed below,
or cancel the writing with C-g and edit the buffer
   to remove or modify the problematic characters,
or specify any other coding system (and risk losing
   the problematic characters).

raw-text no-conversion

Answer (score 1):

I have this setting:

```cl
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
```

And I get no query for your test code.

Comment: Hi abo-abo, I tried your setting, but I still now working, please see the updated questions, I include the message on Emacs.